# Show rows with max number grouped by column

Tags: sql

I have the tables below:

1st table "Project":

| Id | Project | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | test1 |
| 101 | A | test2 |
| 102 | B | test3 |
| 103 | C | test4 |
| 104 | C | test5 |
| 105 | C | test6 |
| 106 | C | test7 |
| 107 | D | test8 |
| 108 | D | test9 |
| 109 | D | test10 |
| 110 | D | test51 |
| 111 | D | test52 |
| 112 | C | test53 |
| 113 | C | test54 |

2nd table "ProjectValue":

| Id | Number | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 10 |
| 101 | 2 | 9 |
| 102 | 3 | 20 |
| 103 | 1 | 80 |
| 104 | 2 | 40 |
| 105 | 3 | 30 |
| 106 | 4 | 10 |
| 107 | 1 | 99 |
| 108 | 2 | 60 |
| 109 | 3 | 40 |
| 110 | 4 | 30 |
| 111 | 5 | 80 |
| 112 | 1 | 100 |
| 113 | 2 | 800 |

I need to show only the value with maximum Number grouped by the Project

| Id | Project | Number | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 102 | A | 3 | 20 |
| 102 | B | 4 | 10 |
| 111 | C | 5 | 80 |
| 113 | D | 2 | 800 |

Comment: Which dbms do you use? Add an appropiate tag to your question. You can do that by click on the edit link, underneath your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it's SQL, it's there

Comment: @MedAmin sql is a language not a dbms, tag your dbms

Comment: A view into his profile, I guess he is using sql-server.

Comment: yes it's sql, but I think when you use sql it does not matter which dbms you use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to show only the value with maximum Number grouped by the Project

Your results seem to have little to do with this.  The typical solution uses window functions:

```
select ppv.*
from (select p.*, pv.number, pv.value,
             row_number() over (partition by p.project order by pv.number desc) as seqnum
      from project p join
           projectvalue pv
           on p.id = pv.id
     ) ppv
where seqnum = 1;
```